# Elixir/Phoenix multiplication

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

I've been working on the project and just found this. Basically if I multiple the integer value by the some kind of decimal(float) the value I receive is not exact. 
For example `<%= 800 * 1.1 %>` in the html, returns `880.0000000000001` instead of just 880.

Any possible explanations to why it happens? And is it possible to round the number?

Edit: `<%= 800 + (800 * 0.1) %>` works fine

Using the reply below, I've modified code to `<%= Float.round(value, 2) %>`, so the value gets rounded to two decimal places

Comment: _"Any possible explanations to why it happens?"_ - [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To round a float use, `round()`

```
<%= 800 * 1.1 |> round %>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've never encountered this issue before

Comment: Hey again, do you know where I can read more about it? I'm interested in specifying number of digits after comma

Comment: that is a bit more complex behaviour, for that you may find answers at Float module here - http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Float.html

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look